# ArgumentNullException exception with Node.NiceUrl, Url, when in BeginRequest event

Tags: umbraco

I need a node's Url on every request, ideally in BeginRequest event, or as early as possible in a request pipeline.

Below is the code in BeginRequest event, with exception:

var node = new Node(1059);

NiceUrl = 'node.NiceUrl' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'

any idea on the earliest event to access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us a little more detail on your code? Is  `var node = new Node(1059);` your only bit of code and are you sure that's the part throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much detail here but if instantiating the node is OK, but accessing NiceUrl is throwing a null exception, that suggests that the node exists but has never been published - publishing the node should generate the nice url.

Perhaps you could consider always storing the node id (rather than the NiceUrl of the node?) - which should exist at all times after being saved initially.

Instead of the NiceUrl you can of course preview the page using something like http:///.aspx, and I think that will be the closest to the actual URL you can have at that stage - so would storing something like '/1234.aspx' be of any use?